# VLANs and IP addressing

Tags: switch, vlan, subnet, ip-address, hp

I have been tasked with setting up some VLANs on 10 HP 2520 switches. This is a departure from my normal IT support area so thought I'd seek out a little advice from more knowledgable people.

These switches are being deployed in a new building on site and will connect into the existing site infrastructure.

So... I need to setup the following VLANs:

Vlan ID: VLAN 53
 Ports: 17-20
 IPs: 10.120.130.0/24
 Gateway:  10.120.130.254
 Description:   SVR
 Device IP Range: 10.12.130.1 - 10.120.130.250

Vlan ID: VLAN 54
 Ports:  1-16
 IPs: 10.120.140.0/24
 Gateway:   10.120.140.254
 Description:   CAM
 Device IP Range: 10.12.140.1 - 10.120.140.250

Vlan ID: VLAN 55
 Ports:  21-24
 IPs: 10.120.150.0/24
 Gateway: 10.120.150.254
 Description: DESK
 Device IP Range: 10.12.150.1 - 10.120.150.250

I've had a play around with the configurations and these are the commands I believe i need to use to create a VLAN on each of the switches.

Step 1: Create the VLANs

```
 HP-Switch(Config)#Vlan 530 name "SVR"
 HP-Switch(Config)#Vlan 540 name "CAM"
 HP-Switch(Config)#Vlan 550 name "DESK"
```

Step 2: Allocate ports to VLANs

```
 HP-Switch(Config)#Vlan 53
 HP-Switch(vlan-53)#untagged 17-20
 HP-Switch(vlan-53)#tagged 48 
 HP-Switch(vlan-53)#exit

 HP-Switch(Config)#Vlan 54
 HP-Switch(vlan-54)#untagged 1-16
 HP-Switch(vlan-54)#tagged 48 
 HP-Switch(vlan-54)#exit

 HP-Switch(Config)#Vlan 55
 HP-Switch(vlan-55)#untagged 21-24
 HP-Switch(vlan-55)#tagged 48 
 HP-Switch(vlan-55)#exit
```

So that should have made the 3 VLANs on specific ports all routing via the tagged port 48.

What I cant understand is how I allocate the IP addresses. I had thought I could use the following command to tell the VLAN what IP range to use but it just comes up saying Bad IP

```
 HP-Switch(vlan-53)# ip address 10.120.130.0 255.255.255.0
```

If i change it to 130.1/24 then the switch is allocated the .1 address meaning I'd have to setup an IP for each of the 10 switches for each of the VLANs meaning there would in effect be 4 managment IPs for each switch.

Do i even need to assign an IP range to the VLAN?  The IP addresses are allocated to specific MAc addresses by the existing DHCP servers.

-UPDATE-

An update to this question.

I have configures one of the VLANS as:

Vlan 55 
   name "DESK"
   untagged 20-22
   tagged 27
   no ip address
   exit

But the onsite IT are saying they dont see any packets tagged as VLAN 55.

The setup is that there are 3 switches in a 'control room' 2xHP 2510 and 1xHP 2920. What I've been told is the 10 x HP 2520 switches I need to configure are connected via fibre to these switches. The 2510's have 4 fibre connections each and the 2920 has the other 2 (making the 10 connections).  these switches then connect (via Cat5e) to the main network/switches (called 'NET1) that we have no control over.

My question now is, do i need to setup any configuration on these switches in order to pass the tagged packets or should the switch just pass them on with the tag (as added by the 'tagged 27' port)?

Comment: You said the gateway for vlan53 is 10.120.130.254, so why are you trying to allocate 10.120.130.0 or 10.120.130.1 on vlan53?  You should be using `HP-Switch(vlan-53)# ip address 10.120.130.254 255.255.255.0`.  The vlan's ip address is the default gateway for that Vlan (assuming you want that switch to be the Default-Gateway)

Comment: I thought that I needed to tell the VLAN what IP range it was using/on 9hence the .0/24 (or .1/24). So what you're saying is that I don't need to explicitly tell the VLAN what IP range it's in only what it's gateway is? so I need to do HP-Switch(vlan-53)# ip address 10.120.130.254 255.255.255.0 . . HP-Switch(vlan-54)# ip address 10.120.140.254 255.255.255.0 etc?

Comment: correct... a combination of interface ip address and netmask limits the range of valid addresses on that vlan

Comment: I'm not sure i understand completely. What your saying is that I can setup VLAN 53 on all the switches using the following commands?


HP-Switch(Config)#Vlan 53 name "SVR"
HP-Switch(Config)#Vlan 53
HP-Switch(vlan-53)#untagged 17-20
HP-Switch(vlan-53)#tagged 48 
HP-Switch(vlan-53)#ip address 10.120.130.254 255.255.255.0
HP-Switch(vlan-53)#exit

One thig I dont understand is I thought the 'IP Address' command was used to set the IP range rather than a gateway?

Do i need to setup any routes?

Comment: Each switch needs a unique address

Comment: You only need to assign an IP on one switch to handle routing for the vlan. Presumably you would pick one switch to route all the vlans.

Comment: You need a device to route between VLANs. The ProCurve 2520 switches are not sufficient. Is there a router or Layer 3 switch in this setup?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The HP 2520 is a layer 2 switch: all you can do with it is bridge the individual VLANs tagged on port 48. Then, as long as what is at the other end of it has the right VLANs, gateway addresses and routing set up, all should be fine.

Update: any intermediate switches will also need the VLANs present: tagged on both the uplink and downlink ports.

You do not need to worry about IP ranges.

Comment: So, assuming all routing is handled by a separate switch then VLAN 53 would be configured on these 10 switches using the following:

 HP-Switch(Config)#Vlan 53 name "SVR" 
 HP-Switch(Config)#Vlan 53 
 HP-Switch(vlan-53)#untagged 17-20 
 HP-Switch(vlan-53)#tagged 48 
 HP-Switch(vlan-53)#exit 


 If I am informed that the switches themselves ar doing routing then I need to add the following command into my config 

 HP-Switch(vlan-53)#ip address 10.120.130.254 255.255.255.0 


 Do I need to setup ip helper for DHCP or does the switch doing the routing handle all that?

Comment: You wouldn't be tagging all the VLANs on the uplink port and also routing locally; instead it would be on a separate VLAN. And no, you don't need ip helper on them.

Comment: setting the configuration for VLAN 55 didn't seem to work, this may be due to switches in between the network and these switches blocking it - see the update to the original question for the latest issues.

Answer (score 0):

After I'd configured the switches in my original post, I additionally had to configure the downstream switches so they knew about the VLANs. Once I did that, everything worked perfectly.

Thanks to everyone that contributed.